# How to speed up `Expand`?

Tags: performance-tuning, polynomials

I found that `Expand` is slow for some polynomials.
For example,
`Expand[(x + y)^100 (x + y + z)^100]; // AbsoluteTiming (*{0.925914, Null}*)`, but `Expand[Expand[(x + y)^100]*Expand[(x + y + z)^100]]; // AbsoluteTiming (*{0.138238, Null}*)` is much faster than `Expand` directly. Is there any method to improve the performance of `Expand`?

Comment: A [related post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/136706/improving-efficiency-of-expand).

Comment: I agree that Expand can be surprisingly slow sometimes. But if there was a simple answer to your question in the generality that you are asking, then it would already have been implemented in Expand. (Right!?) You probably have to restrict the class of expressions where you want to outperform Expand, just saying "polynomial" will not be enough, that is my guess.

Answer (score 2):

`ExpandAll` is noticably faster in this case.
This returns approximately 8 on 13.1 under Windows:

```
 RepeatedTiming[   Expand[(x + y)^100 (x + y + z)^100], 5]/
 RepeatedTiming[ExpandAll[(x + y)^100 (x + y + z)^100], 5]
```

Comment: Your `ExpandAll` code is as fast as OP's `Expand[Expand[(x + y)^100]*Expand[(x + y + z)^100]]` and maybe they do the exact same thing.

Comment: It seems that sometimes `ExpandAll` can be slower than `Expand`. I compared `ExpandAll` with the the usual `Expand` and the folded `Expand` in this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/136710/86543) (in the comments of OP's question). For the expression in that link, the timing was "expand : 11 s,  folded expand 7.4 s expandall 16 s. I guess a folded expand is more likely to always be the fastest as it requires the user to use the structure of the equations to make the fold work.